# Scrolling with SDL2 & Box2d - My Camera isn't keeping up with my player

Tags: c++, box2d, sdl, scrolling

I'm trying to get a game on the google play store before I'm 40 (long held dream to publish a game since the days of the speccy), I have just over a month to go so it's not looking good! Foolishly I decided to use SDL2 and Box2d to write the game, both technologies I have little experience in & to compound my misery I'm a noob at C++ so please bear with me if I've made a common error.

Basically I've managed to get a simple physics simulation up and running and have sorted applying my SDL textures to the box2d collision boxes, that all seems to be fine and dandy, where I've come a cropper is my player moves along a ground entity on the X axis,

I've managed to implement a scrolling background but it doesn't keep pace with the player, in which I mean the player moves across the screen instead of remaining central as I'd like him to and the background scrolls behind him. I've probably completely mis-interpreted how to manage my requirements and after days of searching for reference code I'm now at a bit of a loss.

Hopefully some kind soul can help me realise my dream! I've posted what code I think is relevant but if theres something missing I'll add it.

Player movements

```
// Get the position and angle of the player
playerPos = player.pl_body->GetPosition();
playerDeg = player.pl_body->GetAngle();
playerVel = player.pl_body->GetLinearVelocity();

float velChange = desiredVel - playerVel.x;
float impulse = player.pl_body->GetMass() * velChange; //disregard time factor
player.pl_body->ApplyLinearImpulse( b2Vec2(impulse,0), player.pl_body->GetWorldCenter(), true );
```

SDL2 rendering

```
//Render current frame using clips
SDL_Rect* playerCurrentClip = &playerClips[ plAnimFrame / 2 ];

// Render player texture to x & Y of player entity
gPlayerTexture.render (playerPos.x - player.PLAYER_WIDTH/2, playerPos.y - player.PLAYER_WIDTH/2, playerCurrentClip, playerDeg, NULL, flipType);
```

Camera setup

```
// Setup a surface for the camera area
SDL_Rect camera = {0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT};
// Render background texture
gBackgroundTexture.render (0, 0, &camera, NULL, NULL, flipType);
```

Camera scrolling

```
//Center the camera over the player
camera.x = (playerPos.x + player.PLAYER_WIDTH / 2 ) - SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;


 //Keep the camera in bounds
 if( camera.x < 0 )
 {
     camera.x = 0;
 }
 if( camera.x > LEVEL_WIDTH - camera.w )
 {
     camera.x = LEVEL_WIDTH - camera.w;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted:

```
// Render player texture to x & Y of player entity
gPlayerTexture.render (playerPos.x - player.PLAYER_WIDTH/2, playerPos.y - player.PLAYER_WIDTH/2, playerCurrentClip, playerDeg, NULL, flipType);
```

It appears you are not subtracting the camera.x from the player position.

```
// Render player texture to x & Y of player entity
gPlayerTexture.render (playerPos.x - player.PLAYER_WIDTH/2 -(( camera.x )), playerPos.y - player.PLAYER_WIDTH/2, playerCurrentClip, playerDeg, NULL, flipType);
```

Comment: Keep at it. It has nothing to do with a specific age. It is just all about learning way to increase productivity. People find a million excuses for procrastination, hell I'm procrastinating right now. :)

Comment: Hi Arthur :D Many thanks for the tip, I'll have a test later this evening and let you know how I get on. Cheers for the kind words also!

Comment: Awesome! It's working! Thank you so much for the help! I hav'nt been this chuffed since my son was born!

Comment: I am glad and I learned a new auto-antonym. ;) You are welcome. SDL, box2d and C++ are all challenging.

Comment: lol, now I know what an auto-antonym is so we've both learnt something new :D